# Cannot alter legend title in layered ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following chart:

```
ggplot(data = centmerge, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = centmerge$group)) +
geom_polygon(stat = "identity", fill = "green", color = "black") +
geom_point(data = centavg, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = Performance.Country.Name, size = Action_Absolute_Value/1000000))+  
ggtitle("Contract Costs") +
coord_map("polyconic")+
theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

It creates the following chart:

[image]

My problem is that I cannot alter any of the aesthetics of the geom_point.  For instance I cannot change the color of the points on the graph and I cannot change the legend title.  All additions such as the:

```
theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
    axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

at the end will affect only the geom_polygon().  If I try to change the color of the circles, it reverts to a pale red but then I cannot change it further, and I have had no luck changing the title using theme(), scale_fill_discrete(), labs() or any method.  I first want to change the legend title, but also the color of the circles on the map.  I can change the color of the map, but not the circles.

Comment: Did you try   theme(legend.title = element_blank())?  And labs(fill="New name of legend title")

Comment: You can also create a variable in your data frame for Action_Absolute_Value/1000000), name that variable what you want the legend title to be, and solve your naming problem.

Comment: I have tried the first method.  Didn't work.  The second suggestions worked but it still leaves me without a way to change the colors of the circles.

Comment: Can you not change the color of the points by putting `color = "peachpuff3"` inside the geom_point call? (Don't put it inside `aes()` as it doesn't map to a column of data.) Is there a reason you need to make these edits post-hoc?

Comment: That works.  I thought I had tried that before, but I guess I overlooked it.

Comment: @Gregor: I hope I have not violated the etiquette of SO in incorporating your comment in an answer that was accepted.  Is there a way to share rep?  Or should I upvote your comment?

Comment: @lawyeR no worries---though I do wish you had kept "peachpuff3" as the example color ;). I had assumed that OP *did* have a reason not to edit the code, I may put up a competing answer dealing with the issues in a slightly different way (though I already upvoted your answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing on the comments, here is a proposed approach.

Create a variable in your data frame for Action_Absolute_Value/1000000), name that variable what you want the legend title to be, and solve your legend-title naming problem.

As to coloring the points, per Gregor's comment, add `color = "red"` [or whatever color you choose] inside the geom_point call.

Comment: That works for renaming the legend thanks.  Although now I need to name it without spaces (ie. Value_Amount).   is a bit unsightly but better than before.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a lot of confusion about themes vs. layers. Editing the theme is good for things like the colors of axes and gridlines, but is not the preferred way to do labeling. The `labs` function works for labels of all dimensions, x, y, color, size, etc., as well as title.

For the color of the points, just tell `geom_point` what color you want.

```
ggplot(data = centmerge, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = centmerge$group)) +
  geom_polygon(stat = "identity", fill = "green", color = "black") +
  geom_point(data = centavg,
             aes(x = long, y = lat, group = Performance.Country.Name,
                 size = Action_Absolute_Value/1000000),
             # color goes outside of aes() because it's constant for all points
             color = "peachpuff3") +  
  coord_map("polyconic") +
  labs(x = "", y = "",
       # size will give the name for the size legend
       size = "Action Absolute Value (millions)",
       title = Contract Costs")
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())
```